# Joomla 2.5 - Show Edit Profile Page

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, user-profile, user-management

I am creating website using Joomla 2.5. For login, I am using default Joomla user management system. After I login **sometimes** I see the profile page where I have edit profile option. After I browse some other pages and click on Login, I only see option as "Hi User, Logout". How to bring Edit profile option when I click login?

Also in profile page, I see many details like Editor to use and many things. How to hide those details?

### Edit 1

In [Joomla 3.0](http://joomla30.cloudaccess.net/) I can see edit profile option. (user id and password as demo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Module Manager in the admin panel, there will be a module called "User Menu" which will be associated with a menu, most likely called the same name. Go to edit the "User Menu" module and in the bottom right, are some options to choose which pages the module appears on.

Else, if you would like to have the "Edit Profile" link as part of the login module, you will need to go to the following file:

```
modules/mod_login/tmpl/default.php
```

And add in the necessary code there

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

You can add this via a menu.  Either create a new menu or use an existing menu.  Once inside the menu, You must create a new menu item at this point.  Under Menu Item Type, click select.
Scroll down and you will find User Profile and Edit User Profile.

Comment: that is not what I was talking. check Lodder answer.

Answer (score 1):

Go to modules/mod_login/tmpl/default.php

and right after you have code in this file

```
if ($type == 'logout'):

add the below code code for profile edit link right after
<a href="<?php echo 'index.php?option=com_sociallogin&view=profile&layout=edit';?>" title="My Profile">Edit Profile</a>
```

Comment: i also tried with `<a href="#" title="My Profile">Edit Profile</a>`

Comment: hey could you please look into my problem?

Comment: oh sorry please use this link<a href="<?php echo 'index.php?option=com_users&view=profile&layout=edit';?>

Comment: not working :( I think I am accessing wrong file.... could you please confirm that I have to access file `modules/mod_login/tmpl/default.php`

Comment: you are accessing right file but link working after logged in user if you have paste it after if ($type == 'logout'): this code

Comment: yes, I have tried before and after logout line too... now where i am see any text...

Comment: http://joomla.pleaselogin.me/ it's my working site after login your account link displayed in social login module

Comment: login with sociallogin using fb or any